# Creating a Scheduled Task in Windows Server 2008

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm used to using Windows Server 2003 and to run my Python scripts as a scheduled task I simply followed the below steps: Opened Scheduled Tasks > Add Scheduled Task > Next > select **Python** > Next > Name the task, daily > supplied start time > supplied username and password to run the task.

Server 2008 looks a bit different but after opening Task Scheduler, I first chose Create basic task > gave it a name > chose Daily > start time and date > start program > and this is where I get confused.. I'm now asked to browse for Program/script (which i thought would be my actual python script) and I can Add arguments and Start in (both are optional).  How do I tell the Task Scheduler that the program is a Python program?  Server 2003 gave me a list for that.  If I setup the Task the way I just described and run it, my task simply opens in Notepad and never runs.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set python.exe as the program, and pass your script to it as an argument.